# How to select a TreeNode by Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I've a TreeView that displays hierarchical data, while I select a TreeNode, I generate a series of links that map the path from selected node till root node

Say:
  Root Node --> ChildNode --> SelectedNode

What I need is, while clicking any of these links, select required node in TreeView?

I know that selecting a TreeNode is done through ClientSide using this code:

```
javascript:__doPostBack(TreeView.ClientID,TreeNodeValuePath)
```

and

```
TreeView_SelectNode(TreeView.ClientID_Data, this,TreeNode.ClientID)
```

Ex:

```
    <a style="border-style: none; font-size: 1em;" id="tvMenut1" title="Created On: 1/28/2009 9:50:06 AM" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(tvMenu_Data, this,'tvMenut1');" href="javascript:__doPostBack('tvMenu','s1\\720,63')" class="tvMenu_0 treenodeParent tvMenu_3">
Etravel2000
```

My problem is to get TreeNode.ClientID?

Any suggestion? FYI: this page is an AJAX-Enabled page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get ClientID of a TreeNode using the following method.
You can change which parameter you will use to get a node based on it.

```
    function GetTreeNodeID(nodeTooltip)
    {
        var tree = document.getElementById(TreeView.ClientID); // Change TreeView ClientID.
        var treeLink =  tree.getElementsByTagName('A');    

        for(var element in treeLink)
            if((nodeTooltip == treeLink[element].title) && (treeLink[element].title != ""))                      
                return treeLink[element].id;
    }
```

Then use this code for each TreeNode in TreeView.

```
spanPath.InnerHtml += "<a href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('tvMenu','" + targetNode.ValuePath + "')\" onclick=\"TreeView_SelectNode(tvMenu_Data, this, GetTreeNodeID('" + targetNode.ToolTip + "'));\">" + targetNode.Text + "</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-->&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

While you select a node from spanPath, it will be selected in TreeView.

Answer (score 0):

TreeNode.ClientID as int the ASP.Net control ClientID?

If so, drop this wherever you're trying to pass it: <%= TreeNode.ClientID %>

Answer (score 0):

There is no a TreeNode.ClinetID property for TreeNode object.

Answer (score 0):

Its helpfull for geting node ID from client side.

http://pushpontech.wordpress.com/2007/06/14/getting-treenode-values-on-the-client-side-with-javascript